# Two different M/G/Infinity queues

Tags: statistics, queueing-theory

I need some help with this problem. We have a service system where customers arrive randomly, following a Poisson process (intensity λ). The times that the customers spend in service are independent, following a Weibull distribution with parameters α > 0 and β > 0. The times in service are also independent of the arrival process. The system has an infinite number of service stations and infinite capacity.

In the problem, the system is simulated and we get a set of data. The data is a random sample of number of customers at random times. We do two simulations with the parameters:

α1 = 0.0241
β1 =  2

α2 = 1.75
β2 = 1

Since the system has got an infinite number of service stations and an infinite capacity, we get two different M/G/∞ queues, and in this case it is known that L/W = λ, which gives me the expected number of customers in the system L = λ*W. W is the theoretic average (the expected value) of the Weibull distribution. We get

L1 = 19.980
L2 = 2.000

My question is: What's the reason to why the two simulations behave so differently?

Comment: cos you used significantly different parameters?!

Comment: Well of course, but I'm guessing that's not the answer the people grading are looking for. I can't find the reason how the queues are affected by the different parameters

Comment: because changing the parameter changes the expected value of Weibull distribution? I don't know what you mean and I don't have an answer for you. sorry

Comment: Why are there two different $M/G/\infty$ queues? Shouldn't there just be one?

Answer (score 1):

The analytic result you're discussing for the mean of $L$ is
$$ \lambda \alpha \Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{\beta}\right)$$
which I guess you've obtained, your question definitely suggests this. It's the product of $\lambda$ and the mean waiting time a single customer experiences which is the mean of the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) where the function $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). If we set $\lambda$ to be a constant (say, 1) then we can draw a [3D plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427enksvrf4tr6) and [contour plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427et1gnanl6b3) for different values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ using Wolfram Alpha.

[image: 3D plot of mean queue length, alpha plotted against beta]
[image: Contour plot of mean queue length, alpha plotted against beta]

Observe how steep the function is for small values of $\alpha$ and consider where your $(\alpha,\beta)$ pairs are in this space. As the contour plot shows the function is very steep toward the left, perhaps the behaviour of the Weibull distribution mean has surprised you?